# Suppose a finite set $G$ is closed under associative product and that both cancellation laws hold in $G$. Prove $G$ must be a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, self-learning

Suppose a finite set $G$ is closed under associative product and that both cancellation laws hold in $G$. Prove $G$ must be a group.

I somehow need to prove identity, inverse, that closure holds to prove that set is a group.

How do i begin? Hints?

Please mention the ideas behind the proof?

Thanks.

EDIT

The proof as posted in link below is

[Prove that this is a group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203023/prove-that-this-is-a-group)

I have doubts regarding this proof

1. There exists a element $e$ of G such that $f(e)=a$? Why does it exist?
2. Now as the function is surjective there exists an element $aa_{R} =e$? 
   Why does it exist? What is the role of surjectivity here?

Thanks.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I have edited question .Can you unmark question as Duplicate

Comment: Done. Sorry about the 1 hour delay. Deleting the comments that are no longer needed.

Comment: He chose $f(g)=ag$ because it works. But, really, what else could you even try? You are trying to show that there's an identity, so, given $a$, you want to look at all the products $ag$ to see whether you can show one of them is $a$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson How should i think if i were to seek an alternate proof for this ?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Without defining function

Comment: I don't know how to find an alternate proof, but anyway that would be another question.