# Help on Problem 15 Chapter 1 of Hungerford's Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

Problem 15 of the first chapter, Groups, in Hungerford's Algebra states

> Let $G$ be a nonempty finite set with an associative binary operation such that for all $a, b, c \in G$ , $ab = ac \implies b = c$ and $ba = ca \implies b =c$ . Then G is a group. Show that this conclusion may be false if $G$ is infinite.

It can be deduced from this that the inverse and the identity element are unique, but I can not understand how to attack the problem to prove $G$ may not be a group if it is infinite. How to approach the problem?

Comment: What happens with the positive integers?

Comment: Did you actually prove it is a group when $G$ is finite? You need to do more than just prove inverses and identity are unique *if they exist*; you also need to show they actually do exist.

Comment: In case of positive integers, it is not a group both under multiplication and addition, since there's no inverse( in case of multiplication, viz inverse of 2 is 1/2 but 1/2 isn't an integer) and there's no identity element ( under addition, since 0 isn't a positive integer)

Comment: But the point is that in the positive integers, which are infinite, under either addition or multiplication, the two conditions you have are satisfied. So that’s an example of a set with an associative operation which satisfies the conditions but is not a group.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you I had missed the point. Is there any way to prove the statement without using counterexamples ?

Comment: There are **two** statements to be proven. One of them requires a proof (that in the case of a finite set, the conditions *do* imply you have a group). The other (that when the set is infinite the conditions *do not* imply you have a group) requires a counterexample. You seem to be only asking about the latter. Are you also asking about the former?

Comment: No, I'm asking about the latter, I've proven the former

Comment: And what exactly do you think constitutes a proof that something need not happen which is not a counterexample? Obviously infinite groups exist, so you are not going to be able to show the conclusion does *not* hold in an infinite set. The way to show that “the conclusion **may** be false if $G$ is infinite” is to exhibit a $G$ that is infinite, satisfies the conditions, but is not a group. That *is* a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you, I've got the point

Comment: See also [In a finite monoid, every left cancellable element is right invertible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2453608/242)