# Are finite semi groups which obey cancellation law abelian groups?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, semigroups

I've found this problem in an exercise.
I've searched it in the web but I've found one which says that it is a group but, in my version of the problem it's says that: "show that finite semi groups which obey cancellation law are abelian groups".

Is there a mistake in this problem?

Comment: Is there a mistake in what problem? The answer to the question in the title is no.

Comment: „says it is a group“ and „in my version [...] are groups“ don’t really contradict... Where does the abelian in the title come from?

Comment: Obviously every finite group is a finite semigroup with cancellation, let it be Abelian or not.

Comment: @PrudiiArca that's my question

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/203023/a-finite-cancellative-semigroup-is-a-group).

Comment: @DerekHolt thanks

Comment: @DerekHolt yes I've forgotten to write it as in the title between quotation marks_more specifically I forgot to mention abelian